# Can you use an LED Bayonet bulb in standard 40 or 60W bayonet fitting?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, led, bulb, halogen

First time poster. In short have flipped all my halogen GU10 bulbs over to LED. Only non spotlight is a Bayonet fitting in my bedroom. The halogen (45W candle) in that went this week & I am having trouble finding (am in UK) a reputable brand of halogen bulb to replace it (have uplighters so am OK in the short term).

Can I just use an LED to replace it instead (standard switch - not a dimmer) or would I need to other adjustments (e.g. to the power to step it down?). Am just thinking this may give me a better chance of finding a better bulb (& also cut the electricity bill!).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Is the LED lamp rated for the mains voltage? If it is than it can be a direct replacement.

Comment: Thanks. The supplier actually got in touch (I reached out on Twitter). In this case you couldn't. Don't know what adjustment was needed but they said no ☹

Answer (score 1):

I've not dealt with these myself (but you made me curious): a simple search for B22d LEDs turns up plenty of results; e.g. [these Osram's](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OSRAM-BASE-CLASSIC-lamp-bayonet/dp/B01FR0TX7S) on Amazon. You haven't said what mount these "Bayonet fitting" is, but I assume it's the common one, i.e. B22d. You can find a full list of [Bayonet fittings on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayonet_mount#Light_bulbs), which also tells you how they're identified (usually by base measure).

Comment: Apologies. Thanks - yes it is a B22 - so I can just make a straight switch? Found loads of info on GU10s when switching over, just couldn't find anything on these - so I just assumed there would be an issue.. I also I try & buy certain things in store when I can (which may explain my issues - everywhere seems to be stocking cheap Chinese products  - which when Googled have poor feedback).

Comment: @user8812: the Amazon link also has some [Philips B22's](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01KHILBV6) which have even better reviews...

Comment: @user8812 - Anything sold with a B22 fitting is designed to go into a B22 fitting at mains voltage. If they sell it, you can use it. Simples.